# Spring + Jersey + Access-Control-Allow-Origin deployed on AppFog

Tags: jquery, spring, servlets, jersey

Im not sure why this error is thrown while making a server call on JQuery using Ajax.

My server code is

```
@POST
@Path("/update")
@Produces({ "application/json "})
public Response update(String json) {
    ......
    ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok("test");
    builder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    builder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    return builder.build();
```

And my Jquery code is

```
var URL = "http://........";


$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    //the url where you want to sent the userName and password to
    url: URL,
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function (data) {
    alert("ok"); 
    }
});
```

NOTE: The same code is working fine on Google App Engine.....

Comment: Sorry if it should have been obvious but - what is the error that is thrown?

Comment: the same XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://....... Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in Firefox, Safari or IE. I had the same issue.